# SQL Server dense_rank() on nvarchar column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29073753/getting-the-range-of-a-number-columnmin-max-if-there-are-missing-numbers-in-be/29074745), is it possible to use `dense_rank` properly on an `nvarchar` column?

Here's a [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd73d/1) where I created a `nvarchar` column, see the results yourself, and here's [one where the column is int](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27c24/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible.  But your examples are quite different.  In the first, the values are ordered as:

```
1
11
2
3
4
5
```

In the second like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
11
```

Hence, the results are different.  Numbers stored as strings are treated as strings, not numbers.

EDIT:

There are two ways to "treat the nvarchar()" as a number.  The first is to do a conversion, such as:

```
dense_rank() over (order by cast(Number as decimal)) grp
```

(or whatever type you want).

The second will work if the values are integers and do not have leading zeros:

```
dense_rank() over (order by len(Number), Number) grp
```

Comment: But is it possible to order them numerically on an nvarchar column?

Comment: Thank you, i've been putting the convert/cast in the wrong places. Will be able to accept answer alter